# AppSync GraphQL Mocking Resolver Map Not Generating Unique Items

Tags: javascript, mocking, graphql, aws-appsync, resolver

My mock is not generating unique data for each item, rather each items have the same field value.

**Option 1:** (ideal approach, incorrect results)

The AppSync schema holds an `items` field of `[Model]`, if I put the `Model` resolver by itself, all the `Model` in the `items` list have the same value.

```
const mocks = {
  ModelModelConnection: () => ({
    items: () => new MockList(5),
  }),
  Model: () => ({
    id: casual.uuid,
    name: casual.title,
  }),
};
```

results in...
[image: Results]

---

**Option 2:** (alternative method, correct results)

```
const mocks = {
  ModelModelConnection: () => ({
    items: () => new MockList(5, () => ({
      id: casual.uuid,
      name: casual.title,
    })),
  }),
};
```

[image: Results]

---

I want to go with Option 1, but I can't seem to get unique items to be mocked. Been scratching my head on this one. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is unclear what exactly you are asking or what you want to achieve. What exactly is the problem? What is the expected result?

Comment: @Larce option 1 results in all the same data in the `name` field, while option 2 results in unique data in `name` field. I want to construct the tree using option 1, but the data needs to be unique like in option 2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As shown in [the docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/graphql-tools/mocking.html#Using-MockList-in-resolvers), if you want to generate a different value each time a field's resolver is fired, the mock resolver should be a function, not a value. So instead of:

```
Model: () => ({
  id: casual.uuid,
  name: casual.title,
}),
```

you should do:

```
Model: () => ({
  id: () => casual.uuid,
  name: () => casual.title,
}),
```

This causes `id` and `name` to be called each time the field is resolved.

Comment: Sorry if I missed it, but didn't find this explicitly stated in the docs: When not defining mocks, is the default behaviour of `addMocksToSchema` for mocking an array of Foo to contain two identical Foo objects?